# How can I improve this wrapper for Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Worker {
    protected bool shutdown;
    protected Thread t;

    /// <summary>
    /// defines that we have an auto unpause scheduled
    /// </summary>
    private bool _unpauseScheduled;

    /// <summary>
    /// when paused; schedule an automatic unpause when we
    /// reach this datetime
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime pauseUntil;


    private bool _isStopped = true;
    public bool IsStopped {
        get {
            return t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped;
        }
    }

    private bool _isPaused = false;
    public bool IsPaused {
        get {
            return _isPaused;
        }
    }

    private string stringRepresentation;

    public Worker() {  
        t = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
        stringRepresentation = "Thread id:" + t.ManagedThreadId;
        t.Name = stringRepresentation;
    }

    public Worker(string name) {   
        t = new Thread(ThreadFunction);
        stringRepresentation = name;
        t.Name = stringRepresentation;
    }


    public void Start() {
        OnBeforeThreadStart();
        t.Start();
    }

    public void ScheduleStop() {
        shutdown = true;
    }

    public void SchedulePause() {
        OnPauseRequest();
        _isPaused = true;
    }

    public void SchedulePause(int seconds) {
        _unpauseScheduled = true;
        pauseUntil = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds);
        SchedulePause();
    }

    public void Unpause() {
        _isPaused = false;
        _unpauseScheduled = false;            
    }

    public void ForceStop() {
        t.Abort();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The main thread loop.
    /// </summary>
    private void ThreadFunction() {
        OnThreadStart();
        while (!shutdown) {
            OnBeforeLoop();
            if (!IsPaused) {
                if (!OnLoop()) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                // check for auto-unpause;
                if (_unpauseScheduled && pauseUntil < DateTime.Now) {
                    Unpause();
                }
            }
            OnAfterLoop();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        OnShutdown();           
    }


    public abstract void OnBeforeThreadStart();
    public abstract void OnThreadStart();
    public abstract void OnBeforeLoop();
    public abstract bool OnLoop();
    public abstract void OnAfterLoop();
    public abstract void OnShutdown();
    public abstract void OnPauseRequest();


    public override string ToString() {
        return stringRepresentation;
    }
}
```

I use this class to create Threads that are designed to run for the lifetime of the application, but also with the ability to pause and stop the threads as needed.

I can't help but shake the feeling that my implementation is naive though. My use of Thread.Sleep() gives me pause. I am still learning the ins and outs of threads, and I am looking to see what others might do instead.

The Worker derived objects need to be able to do the following:

1. Run for the lifetime of the application (or as long as needed)
2. Be able to stop safely (finish what is was doing in OnLoop())
3. Be able to stop unsafely (disregard what is happening in OnLoop())
4. Be able to pause execution for a certain amount of time (or indefinitly)

Now, my implementation works, but that is not good enough for me. I want to use good practice, and I could use some review of this to help me with that.

Comment: If the code is working and you want advice. It would be better for you to hit up Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mikanikal I didn't know that exchange existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't help but shake the feeling that my implementation is naive though. My use of Thread.Sleep() gives me pause. I am still learning the ins and outs of threads, and I am looking to see what others might do instead.

Your intuitions are good here; this is a naive approach, and any time you sleep a thread in production code you should think hard about whether you're making a mistake. You're paying for that worker; why are you paying for it to sleep?

The right way to put a thread to sleep until it is needed is not to sleep and poll in a loop. Use an appropriate wait handle instead; that's what wait handles are for.

But a better approach still would be to put an idle thread back into a pool of threads; if the work needs to be started up again in the future, schedule it onto a new worker thread. A thread that can sleep forever is a huge waste of resources; remember, *a thread is a million bytes of memory by default*. Would you allocate a bunch of million-byte arrays and then never use them?

You should study the design of the Task Parallel Library for additional inspiration. The insight of the TPL is that threads are *workers*, but what you care about is *getting tasks completed*.  Your approach puts a thin layer on top of threads, but it does not get past the fact that threads are workers; managing workers is a pain. State your tasks, and let the TPL assign them to workers.

You might also examine the assumptions around the up-to-date-ness of your various flags. They have no locks and are not volatile, and therefore reads and writes can be moved forwards and backwards in time basically at the whim of the CPU.

You also have some non-threading bugs to think about. For example, suppose you decide to pause for thirty minutes, but at five minutes before clocks "spring forward" for daylight savings time. Do you pause for half an hour, or five minutes? Which do you actually intend?

Comment: Thank you so much for the insightful review! I was reviewing the Task Parallel Library after I posted this. Am I correct in assuming that I would use that instead, and just pass it methods that loop forever (or for as long as they need to)? My Thread.Sleep(1000) only exists to stop the CPU from spinning out of control. By using the Task Library, I could avoid the need to do that altogether?

Comment: Also, am I correct in assuming that I could (and should) replace the Thread.Sleep(1000) with myAutoRestEvent.WaitOne(1000)?

Comment: @user984444: What I was getting at there was that it might be better to put the thread to sleep by waiting indefinitely, and then schedule a timer to signal the sleeping thread to wake it up. Timers are built by experts to be efficient and accurate, so use them.

Comment: @user984444: And yes, you *certainly* do not want to spin! Spin when you are waiting for *nanoseconds*, not for *seconds*. The question at hand is not whether to spin or not, but rather, if you must sleep then how should you be woken up?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on some interesting concepts related to wrapping threads.

I have called it `Fiber` for now.

http://net7mma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Concepts/Classes/Threading/Threading.cs

Eric Lippert is is correct about `paying a worker to sleep` in some regard, if you imagine Eric Lippert is paid salary as opposed to via the hour then technically he is paid to sleep just as any other salaried employee.

How this relates to the concept at hand?

What about Priority? The CPU(s) that are executing your code are contending with their own pipelines for execution context as well as requests from the scheduler.

No one makes any mention of reducing the `Priority` which will reduce the amount of time given to execution of the context by the scheduler.

Chaining the `Priority` will thus increase the amount of cycles given to other context's and additionally will reduce the power consumption of your processor at the same time making your application run longer if it has a limited source of power (unless of course your using the excess heat to provide additional power to your system.)

Comment: You may wish to avoid "fiber", which already has a meaning in the world of threading. A fiber is like a thread in that it has its own stack and point of control, but fibers are cooperatively scheduled; that is, a fiber that is being hosted by a particular thread says "I am done for now, fiber X should now take over this thread".  If you need to write your own scheduler but don't want to write your own operating system, fibers are one way to go.